# Detect all red shades in image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, types, camera, detect

I have some image which I get from a camera and I need to detect red color in the image.

The problem is that is not an ideal `red(255,0,0)`, so i need to write some matlab code which include all the possible shades of red.

Do you have some ideas to do it?

Comment: How do you define _all the possible shades of red_?

Comment: Your idea of "red" (as given in this question) is a construction in your mind.  It would take some serious machine learning to recreate human understanding of color...for instance telling whether something is in a shadow or not, and extrapolating from it.  And even then people don't all agree.  See [color illusions](http://brainden.com/color-illusions.htm), for instance.  The machine's "understanding" of Red is exactly what you've got in the tuple... the R component of an RGB value, and that's all there "actually" is.

Comment: But i am not define the red, it is the camera that define it. if there is some object which is red and the camera invert it to burgundy for example, how could i know that is a part of the red object?